# saving data to txt file using PHP

Tags: php

i'm new with php and cant understand how to do that right. i'm trying to save to input data into a txt file.

if have this html form:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<div>
<label for="theDate">When?</label>
<input type="text" data-inline="true" name="theDate"  />
<label for="theNote">What?</label>
<input type="text" data-inline="true" name="theNote"  />
</div>
<button type="submit" data-inline="true">Save Note</button>
</form>
```

test.php look like that:

```
<?php
$f = fopen("notes.txt", "a");
fwrite($f, $_POST["theDate"] . $_POST["theNote"]);  //chris85 suggest..
fclose($f);
?>
```

what am i doing wrong? 
and how can i add message for success (or error) after submit?

Comment: How do you think - what is this `$_POST["theDate" + "theNote"]`?

Comment: Is there any error messages?

Comment: the browser display "test.php" on the address bar, and a blank screen. when checking the txt file - nothing saved.

Comment: But when you submit the form does it appear any errors?

Comment: `$_POST["theDate"] . $_POST["theNote"]`

Comment: Yeah, I saw that too